# Are there libraries for data visualization (except for Matplotlib) to use in the Tkinter app Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, visualization

I want to create a Tkinter app in which the user can enter the data (just by choosing the Excel file) and can see the graphs by using Tkinter Check Buttons. So I decided to use Matplotlib for that, but it opens in another new window. It will be excellent if those charts open in the same window. (I also would prefer if that library would show the charts as Plotly Express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upload a minimum reproducible example.
Without seeing that, you need to create a `FigureCanvasTkAgg` canvas to add your plots to if you haven't ([docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html#embedding-in-tk)).

```
import tkinter

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import numpy as np


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
ax = fig.add_subplot()
line, = ax.plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))
ax.set_xlabel("time [s]")
ax.set_ylabel("f(t)")

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()

# pack_toolbar=False will make it easier to use a layout manager later on.
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root, pack_toolbar=False)
toolbar.update()

canvas.mpl_connect(
    "key_press_event", lambda event: print(f"you pressed {event.key}"))
canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", key_press_handler)

button_quit = tkinter.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=root.quit)


def update_frequency(new_val):
    # retrieve frequency
    f = float(new_val)

    # update data
    y = 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * t)
    line.set_data(t, y)

    # required to update canvas and attached toolbar!
    canvas.draw()


slider_update = tkinter.Scale(root, from_=1, to=5, orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
                              command=update_frequency, label="Frequency [Hz]")

# Packing order is important. Widgets are processed sequentially and if there
# is no space left, because the window is too small, they are not displayed.
# The canvas is rather flexible in its size, so we pack it last which makes
# sure the UI controls are displayed as long as possible.
button_quit.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)
slider_update.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)
toolbar.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM, fill=tkinter.X)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

tkinter.mainloop()
```